# Splitting $N$ Groups of Objects into $M$ bins

Tags: combinatorics

For simplicity, I'll give the example as splitting 3 bins of balls into 4 bins.

- Bin 1 contains $N_1$ blue balls, bin 2 $N_2$ red balls, and bin 3 $N_3$ green balls

How many combinations of ways are there to split these balls into 4 distinct output bins?

How do you generalize this problem for $N$ bins of balls into $M$ distinct output bins?

EDIT: to show some of my research and thoughts

This is similar to the so-called ["Stirling numbers of the second kind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), but the difference is that only some of the objects are distinct, not all of them.  I was thinking of trying to reduce the problem to that one but I've come up short.

EDIT: for full disclosure, I asked this question to help solve this [Project Euler Question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=495)

Comment: What ideas do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: By Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia) the number of ways to distribute the blues, assumed indistinguishable, is $\binom{N_1+4-1}{4-1}$. For each of these ways $\dots$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I came across this but didn't make the connection that I could reduce my problem to this one.  Is my math correct that the answer to my problem would be $\prod_{i=1}^{N}\binom{N_i+M-1}{M-1}$?

Comment: Disregard my comment, now deleted, I see you edited. Yes, your revised formula is right in the general case.